# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NullBuster'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Environment: SQL server 2008 R2.

I have the following SP which is supposed to copy data from a table from MainDB to MiniDB to the tables that are identical schema wise. but I get this error when I run it:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Start Copying table: varUser at 2013-10-22 11:37:54
Bulk copy error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NullBuster', table 'MainDB.dbo.varUser'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "usp_BulkCopy": 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: 
   at StoredProcedures.usp_BulkCopy(String sourceServer, String sourceDatabase, String sourceSelectQuery, String destinationServer, String destinationDatabase, String destinationTable, Boolean FlagKeepIdentity, Boolean throwExceptionOnErrors, Boolean SourceTrusted, Boolean DestTrusted, String SourceUser, String SourcePass, String DestUser, String DestPass, String ColumnMappings)
.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "usp_BulkCopy": 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: 
   at StoredProcedures.usp_BulkCopy(String sourceServer, String sourceDatabase, String sourceSelectQuery, String destinationServer, String destinationDatabase, String destinationTable, Boolean FlagKeepIdentity, Boolean throwExceptionOnErrors, Boolean SourceTrusted, Boolean DestTrusted, String SourceUser, String SourcePass, String DestUser, String DestPass, String ColumnMappings)
.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

here is how I run it:

```
exec dbo.sp_Copy_MYDB_Subset_Tables1 'Server1\Instance','MainDB',''Server1\Instance','Mini_DB'
```

here is the SP.

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Copy_MYDB_Subset_Tables1]    Script Date: 10/22/2013 11:21:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Copy_MYDB_Subset_Tables1](
    @vSourceServer      varchar(255)
    ,@vSourceDatabase   varchar(255) = 'MYDB'
    ,@vDestinationServer    varchar(255)
    ,@vDestinationDatabase  varchar(255) = 'MYDB'
    ,@vIsServerOnDomain     BIT = 1 --
    ,@TargetDBUserName  varchar(255) = ''
    ,@TargetDBPassword  varchar(255) = ''

    )  
AS
BEGIN 

    Declare 
    @vSourceTable   varchar(255)
    ,@vSourceSelectQuery    varchar(255)
    ,@vDestinationTable     varchar(255)
    ,@vReturn               int 
    ,@vReturnMessage        varchar(max) 
    ,@vPeriodtoArchive      int
    ,@ColumnMappings        varchar(4000)


BEGIN TRY


     if (@vSourceServer is null or @vSourceServer = '')
        set @vSourceServer = @@servername


    if object_id('tempdb..#TempTableCopyList') is not null
        drop table #TempTableCopyList

    Create Table #TempTableCopyList
    (
        id [int] NOT NULL  primary key clustered
        ,TableName      varchar(100)
        ,ColumnMappings varchar(4000)
        ,DateCopied     datetime
    )

    insert into #TempTableCopyList
        Select id, TableName, ColumnMappings, DateCopied
        from dbo.fn_Get_MYDB_Subset_TableList()
        where TableName = 'varuser' -- just to test with one table.

    declare c cursor for 
    Select TableName, ColumnMappings 
        from #TempTableCopyList
           order by id desc


    open c

    fetch next from c into @vSourceTable, @ColumnMappings

    While @@fetch_status =0 BEGIN


                print 'Start Copying table: ' + @vSourceTable + ' at ' + convert(varchar(30),getdate(),120)

                Set @vSourceSelectQuery = 'Select * from ' + @vSourceTable + ' with (nolock) '

        IF @vIsServerOnDomain = 0
        BEGIN
                exec master.dbo.usp_BulkCopy 
                     @vSourceServer
                    ,@vSourceDatabase
                    ,@vSourceSelectQuery
                    ,@vDestinationServer
                    ,@vDestinationDatabase
                    ,@vSourceTable
                    ,1
                    ,1
                    ,true
                    ,false
                    ,''
                    ,''
                    ,@TargetDBUserName  
                    ,@TargetDBPassword
                    ,@ColumnMappings
        END
        ELSE BEGIN

                exec master.dbo.usp_BulkCopy 
                     @vSourceServer
                    ,@vSourceDatabase
                    ,@vSourceSelectQuery
                    ,@vDestinationServer
                    ,@vDestinationDatabase
                    ,@vSourceTable
                    ,1
                    ,1
                    ,true
                    ,true
                    ,''
                    ,''
                    ,''
                    ,''
                    ,@ColumnMappings
        END
                UPDATE #TempTableCopyList
                    set DateCopied = GETDATE()
                WHERE TableName = @vSourceTable




        fetch next from c into @vSourceTable, @ColumnMappings

    END

    close c
    deallocate c

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    close c
    deallocate c
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrorMessage = error_message()
    print @vSourceTable + '; '+ @vSourceServer+ '; '+  @vSourceDatabase+ '; '+ @vDestinationServer+ '; '+ @vDestinationDatabase+ '; '+ @vDestinationTable
    Print @ErrorMessage
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 0, 1)

END CATCH

    --INFORMATIONAL
    SELECT * FROM #TempTableCopyList

    drop table #TempTableCopyList

return 

END


GO
```

what causes this error? I was thinking it would be the .net version, it doesn't seem like. the able "varuser" does have null values in some of the columns. Could that be the cause? If that is the cause, how can make these work with NULL values in the columns?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Given the message

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NullBuster', table 'MainDB.dbo.varUser'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I would imagine that the column `nullbuster` in the table `varUser` is set to not allow nulls, and you're trying to insert one into it.

Comment: I thought so as well. But there is no column as nullbuster in the table. So I thought it could be a cryptic SQL server's way of saying something.

Comment: It's not a SQL Server message. There's something in `usp_BulkCopy`. I'm guessing from the name nullbuster, it's specifically designed to prevent nulls.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: **table 'MainDB.dbo.varUser'; column does not allow nulls**. You have to alter the table structure to insert null values into the required column.